# Ubuntu "connect to server" dialogue and private keys

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, private-key

Ubuntu has a "connect to server" dialogue option selectable from the desktop menu.  However, for SSH it only seems to allow a username/password login.

Is it possible to use a username/private key login instead?  If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a private key in `~/.ssh/id_(d|r|ecd)sa` it will automatically use that key. Just enter the username (or `ssh://username@hostname/`) and no password.

Comment: Are you talking about from the commandline?  I'm talking about from the "Connect to server" dialogue.

Comment: @GordonM No, I'm talking about the GUI. *If* you have a key at `~/.ssh/id_(d|r|ecd)sa` the GUI will automatically select that key (as under the hood it's just using `ssh`).

Comment: I do have a key there but it's not picking it up.  The password box just continually displays a red ! icon